# Solana web3.js set mint and freeze authority null

Tags: web3js, solana

Trying to set mint and freeze authority of my instruction to null but I get an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toBuffer' of null
    at pubkeyToBuffer (/node_modules/@solana/spl-token/lib/index.cjs.js:73:39)
```

Here's the code

```
Token.createInitMintInstruction(
   TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // program id
   mint.publicKey, // mint
   decimals, // decimals
   null, // mint Authority
   null, // freeze Authority
)
```

How can I do this? If possible without updating after creation.

Answer (score 3):

Ok solved it by updating the authority after mint via another 2 instructions for each authority type. Strange nonetheless this apparently can't be done on initial mint instruction.

```
Token.createSetAuthorityInstruction(
   TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // program id
   account, // account
   null, // new authority
   'MintTokens', // type - 'FreezeAccount' for freeze authority
   authority, // authority
   [], // signers
)
```

Comment: You've understood most of it.  You can't set the mint authority to null on init, likely because no tokens have been minted.  You can, however, set the freeze authority to null on init.